# Connect arduino to beaglebone black

Tags: serial, usb, uart

I want to exchange some date between arduino and beaglebone, as far as I know, most arduinos works with 5v levels, so I need to convert 5v into 3.3v beaglebone in order to communicate with it.
Unfortunatly I have no pro mini 3.3v now, only 5v arduinos.
So I need to convert levels.
I have several questions.

1. I have UART TTL CP2102 converter, I am using it to programm my Arduino pro mini, can I use it directly with beagle bone without converter ? [http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/410n8%2BHhdNL.*SY300*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/410n8%2BHhdNL._SY300_.jpg) like this.
2. I can buy this cable with pl2303 inside http://i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/32250361345/Free-postage-1pcs-PL2303-PL2303HX-USB-to-UART-TTL-Cable-module-4p-4-pin-RS232-Converter.jpg
3. Is it possible to power my arduino pro mini 5v with 3.3v supply and use it directly with beaglebone

   4. Can you provide simple level converter schematic to solder it quickly

All in all I need just to communicate with beaglebone via uart from pc with USB-UART converter or from arduino it doesn't matter, just to communicate and send some data.

Please suggest what is the best way to follow.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is just to plug the Arduino in to the BBB.

The BBB has USB.  The Arduino has USB.  Connect the two together and you have both power and data immediately available.

Depending on the Arduino and its version it will either be there as `/dev/ttyAMA0` or `/dev/ttyUSB0`

You can even use `avrdude` to upload new software to the Arduino direct from the BBB.

Comment: Thx for answer, but I need UART communication

Comment: @solderingiron  Why? What's so special about using the UART pins that you can't achieve just as easily through the USB CDC/ACM UART emulation?